# How to check ipaddresses variable from vsphere_guest results in playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have playbook which deploy vitrual machine. I want delay run playbook until vm get ip-address. I try make loop but have error.

```
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        guest: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: vsphere_facts
      until: vsphere_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] = "192.168.250.*"
      retries: 20
      delay: 60
```

> {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check
>   'vsphere_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] =
>   \"192.168.250.*\"' failed. The error was: template error while
>   templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='.
>   String: {% if vsphere_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] =
>   \"192.168.250.*\" %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}

Comment: Try `==` instead of `=`... And this will not work because of `*`. You need to use `match` filter.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov yep, `==` working. Please, give an example `match ` or give an URL, as i don't could not find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should opt for:

```
until: vsphere_facts.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0] | match("192.168.250.")
```

Direct comparison (with `==`) can't handle wildcards like `*`.